# Drupal: Correcting URL link access for subdirectory site Installation

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal

I've installed Drupal 7 to a sub-directory on my server and used .htaccess mod_rewrites to fix most of the URL pathing issues, I'm now looking for a way to strip the sub-directory from the URL when it's explicitly requested.

To be clear, the site can be accessed from 'example.com' and the internal links work fine, but I'm looking to prevent requests to 'example.com/sub/file' from working, Ideally with a 301 back to 'example.com/file'.

My .htaccess at the moment looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ sub/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sub%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* sub/$0 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* sub/index.php?Q$0 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding:

`Redirect 301 /\/sub/file http://www.example.com/file`

to your .htaccess?

Comment: That would only work for the one file though, I was looking to strip-out the directory from every URL with a more general rule. Best I could come up with was:
    `RewriteRule ^/sub/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]`
But that just caused a rewrite loop because of the other rules.